# Imageview in LinearLayout won't take parameters

Tags: android, parameters

How come my LinearLayout with dynamically added images won't take parameters ?

```
    LinearLayout ImageView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    LinearLayout ImageView2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settings2);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imagev = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imagev.topMargin=2;

ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);
            image.setId(Integer.parseInt(listitems.get(n).get("cbid")));
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    showpopup(v.getId());
                }
            });
            if (listitems.get(n).get("state").toString().equals("1")) {
                cb.setChecked(true);
                my_checked_layout.addView(cb,params);
                cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 184, 239, 220));
                cb.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                ImageView2.addView(image, imagev);
            } else {
                cb.setChecked(false);
                cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 19, 202, 140));
                cb.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                my_layout.addView(cb,params);
                ImageView.addView(image,imagev);
            }
```

The my_checked_layout(cb, params); does take the other params

[image: deviceImage]

my XML, where the images and checkboxes are being set.
the parts that are being used are in both linear layouts with the id's Parent & parent2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Name Label -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- green -->
    <!-- Email Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#EB0505" />
    <!-- red -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF00FF" />
    <!-- pink -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#13ca8c"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/devider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Parent2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/checked"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#B8EFDC" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If this is the code, it won't take them b/c it won't compile.  The `OnClickListener` isn't closed where it probably should be.

Comment: My bad, i was just showing the code needed, the `OnClickListener` is closed as it should be, my `ImageView2.addView(image,imagev)` is in a if statement directly under the above code. And yes i am sure it goes in the if statement (there's also a else with the same `addView`).

Comment: @user3671459 which line of code that dont take parameters?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin   `ImageView2(image,imagev);` and `ImageView.addView(image,imagev);`

Comment: @user3671459 post ImageView2 and ImageView where you initialized it

Comment: @user3671459 what does the compiler is saying?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it says nothing, it runs and it does all my interactions with the ImageView but just not that margins..

Comment: i do. imagev.topMargin(2); or isn't that what you mean

Comment: if i do that, only the first imageView takes that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add margin within the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` you can call the setMargin() method of it.

**example:**

```
setMargins(135, 176, 0, 0);
```

where `setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

Comment: I had that. with `imagev.topMargin(2);` 
which didn't work, and your answer also doesn't.. thats the odd thing

Comment: @user3671459 try padding instead

Comment: Done that also.. It's multiple imageViews which need a spacing between each other

Comment: @user3671459 instead of ViewGroup.LayoutParams change it to LinearLayout.LayoutParams. and try it with padding

Comment: @user3671459 can you post a picture of the current resulkt

Comment: its posted. what i want is that trashcan to follow along the line of the items. left of it.

Comment: @user3671459 post the xml of the activity

Comment: its posted. havent figured it out myself yet... :(